# Looking for a term to describe an obnoxious behavior

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the term when someone says how busy they are but in a sarcastic way, such as, Sure, I can do that for you, because I have absolutely nothing else to do. Work related for someone who constantly says, sure I just sit around eating bon bons all day. She's trying to make sure that everyone knows how busy she is. There has to be a word!

Comment: Why do you think there must be a word? There isn’t a word for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see what’s wrong with *[sarcastic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sarcastic)*. If you don’t like that, there are plenty of [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sarcastic) for it.